# How to tilt the whole drawing set

Tags: tikz-pgf, siunitx

How to tilt the whole drawing at an angle equal to 30°?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{vertical custom shading/.code={%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@middle{#1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@bottom{\tikz@vcs@middle/2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@top{(100-\tikz@vcs@middle)/2+\tikz@vcs@middle}
        \pgfdeclareverticalshading[tikz@axis@top,tikz@axis@middle,tikz@axis@bottom]{newaxis}{100bp}{%
            color(0bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(\tikz@vcs@bottom bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(\tikz@vcs@middle bp)=(tikz@axis@middle);
            color(\tikz@vcs@top bp)=(tikz@axis@top);
            color(100bp)=(tikz@axis@top)}
        \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/shading=newaxis}
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]

    \begin{scope}[scale=1]  
    \path[bottom color=gray!50!black,top color=gray!10, postaction={pattern=north east lines,rotate=30}] ((0,3) rectangle (5,2.7) (0,3) edge (5,3) ;
    \end{scope}


    \begin{scope}[scale=1,xshift=1cm,yshift=3cm]

    pics/hook/.style={code={
            \pgfgettransformentries{\tmpa}{\tmpb}{\tmpc}{\tmpd}{\tmp}{\tmp}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myJacobian}{sqrt(abs(\tmpa*\tmpd-\tmpb*\tmpc))}  
            \draw[rotate=-90,scale=0.24,yshift=5.2cm,xshift=-3.2cm,double distance=.3mm, double=gray!80,color=black!78,line width=\myJacobian*.7pt,line cap=round]
            (.25,-1.1) -- (.25,-0.8) to[out=90,in=240] (0.6,-0.4)
            arc[start angle=-30,end angle=220,x radius=0.44cm,y radius=0.445cm];}

        \filldraw [scale=1.2,xshift=-.16cm,rounded corners=4pt,left color=black!95,right color=black,middle color=black!70, vertical custom shading=60, shading angle=90] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle

        node [inner sep=2pt,rounded corners=1pt,fill=gray!30,
        text=black] at (.5,.5) {{\small M}};},

    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add `rotate=30` to the options of the `tikzpicture` environment then you get:

[image]

For completeness, even though I've already descried the change, here is your updated code :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{vertical custom shading/.code={%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@middle{#1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@bottom{\tikz@vcs@middle/2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@top{(100-\tikz@vcs@middle)/2+\tikz@vcs@middle}
        \pgfdeclareverticalshading[tikz@axis@top,tikz@axis@middle,tikz@axis@bottom]{newaxis}{100bp}{%
            color(0bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(\tikz@vcs@bottom bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(\tikz@vcs@middle bp)=(tikz@axis@middle);
            color(\tikz@vcs@top bp)=(tikz@axis@top);
            color(100bp)=(tikz@axis@top)}
        \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/shading=newaxis}
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round, rotate=30]

    \begin{scope}[scale=1]
    \path[bottom color=gray!50!black,top color=gray!10, postaction={pattern=north east lines,rotate=30}] ((0,3) rectangle (5,2.7) (0,3) edge (5,3) ;
    \end{scope}


    \begin{scope}[scale=1,xshift=1cm,yshift=3cm]

    pics/hook/.style={code={
            \pgfgettransformentries{\tmpa}{\tmpb}{\tmpc}{\tmpd}{\tmp}{\tmp}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myJacobian}{sqrt(abs(\tmpa*\tmpd-\tmpb*\tmpc))}
            \draw[rotate=-90,scale=0.24,yshift=5.2cm,xshift=-3.2cm,double distance=.3mm, double=gray!80,color=black!78,line width=\myJacobian*.7pt,line cap=round]
            (.25,-1.1) -- (.25,-0.8) to[out=90,in=240] (0.6,-0.4)
            arc[start angle=-30,end angle=220,x radius=0.44cm,y radius=0.445cm];}

        \filldraw [scale=1.2,xshift=-.16cm,rounded corners=4pt,left color=black!95,right color=black,middle color=black!70, vertical custom shading=60, shading angle=90] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle

        node [inner sep=2pt,rounded corners=1pt,fill=gray!30,
        text=black] at (.5,.5) {{\small M}};},

    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer. Rotate it with zero opacity to get the correct bounding box and then use `transform canvas` to rotate it. The shadings get rotated but not the patterns. You can rotate the patterns with the `patterns.meta` library, if needed.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{vertical custom shading/.code={%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@middle{#1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@bottom{\tikz@vcs@middle/2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@top{(100-\tikz@vcs@middle)/2+\tikz@vcs@middle}
        \pgfdeclareverticalshading[tikz@axis@top,tikz@axis@middle,tikz@axis@bottom]{newaxis}{100bp}{%
            color(0bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(\tikz@vcs@bottom bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(\tikz@vcs@middle bp)=(tikz@axis@middle);
            color(\tikz@vcs@top bp)=(tikz@axis@top);
            color(100bp)=(tikz@axis@top)}
        \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/shading=newaxis}
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  \def\Whatever{\begin{scope}[scale=1]  
    \path[bottom color=gray!50!black,top color=gray!10, postaction={pattern=north east lines,rotate=30}] ((0,3) rectangle (5,2.7) (0,3) edge (5,3) ;
    \end{scope}


    \begin{scope}[scale=1,xshift=1cm,yshift=3cm]
        \filldraw [scale=1.2,xshift=-.16cm,rounded corners=4pt,left color=black!95,right color=black,middle color=black!70, vertical custom shading=60, shading angle=90] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle
        node [inner sep=2pt,rounded corners=1pt,fill=gray!30,
        text=black] at (.5,.5) {{\small M}};
    \end{scope}}
   \begin{scope}[opacity=0,rotate=30]
     \Whatever
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=30}]
     \Whatever
   \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to rotate pattern.

Comment: @moumou85 You can do that with `patterns.meta`, as I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to customize pattern using the following code:

Into the preambule:

```
\tikzdeclarepattern{
    name=hatch,
    parameters={\hatchsize,\hatchangle,\hatchlinewidth},
    bounding box={(-.1pt,-.1pt) and (\hatchsize+.1pt,\hatchsize+.1pt)},
    tile size={(\hatchsize,\hatchsize)},
    tile transformation={rotate=\hatchangle},
    defaults={
        hatch size/.store in=\hatchsize,hatch size=5pt,
        hatch angle/.store in=\hatchangle,hatch angle=0,
        hatch linewidth/.store in=\hatchlinewidth,hatch linewidth=.4pt,
    },
    code={
        \draw[line width=\hatchlinewidth] (0,0) -- (\hatchsize,\hatchsize);
    }
}
```

and this in document,

```
\draw [pattern={hatch[hatch size=4pt, hatch linewidth=.4pt, hatch angle=90]}, pattern color=black] [preaction={bottom color=gray!70!black,top color=gray!10}] ((0,3) rectangle (5,2.7) (0,3) edge (5,3) ;
```

and to rotate I use:

```
\begin{turn}{angle}
\end{turn}
```

Thanx all for your answers.